# Angular 2 eventEmitter not work

Tags: typescript, angular

All did well as in the manual, here's the code:
WebSocketBroadcaster

```
import {EventEmitter, Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class WebSocketBroadcaster {
    ee: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
}
```

WebSocketService  [code](http://pastebin.com/bkns36My)

bootstrap

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    appRouterProviders,
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms(),
    WebSocketBroadcaster
])
```

client component  [code](http://pastebin.com/TDK7yTHX)

`console.log(data)` in client.component does not work
`console.log(this.broadcaster.ee);` output
[image: output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EventEmitter` are not supposed to be used in services. `EventEmitter` is only for `@Output()` properties in components.

In services use `Observable` and `Subject` instead.

Comment: Any link, example? Is using EventEmitter forbidden or just not recommended?

Comment: Misko Hevery mentioned it in a comment in GitHub issues that `EventEmitter`, even though it is currently based on `Subject`, is subject to change at any time without prior notice. There is currently no known problem using it for something else, except as mentioned, that your app might break with a future Dart version.